# matlab: find the index of common values at the same entry from two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

Suppose that I have two arrays of size `p` (`p` is large) that have values from `0,1,2`. I am looking for a way to find the index that both arrays have value `2` at the same entry, the index that one has value `2` and the other one has value `1`, etc (like `2` and `2`, `2` and `1`, `` `2 and ``0`,`1`and`1`,`1`and`0`).

Is there a way to achieve this without using the for loop on `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical arrays, let `A` and `B` be your arrays (with consistent sizes):

```
Indices=find((A==2)&(B==2));
```

Etc. for other operations.

Note that if `A` and `B` have dimensions higher than 1, `Indices` will be a linear index, change to `[x,y]=find((A==2)&(B==2));` if you want row/column pairs.

Comment: It is slightly more optimal to do (A==2)&(B==2) rather than .*

Comment: @MattJ You're right, also because if you happen to need OR operand you can just switch to `|`.