# Optimize parameters of a pairwise distance function in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, find

This question is related to [matlab: find the index of common values at the same entry from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409275/matlab-find-the-index-of-common-values-at-the-same-entry-from-two-arrays).

Suppose that I have an `1000` by `10000` matrix that contains value `0`,`1`,and `2`. Each row are treated as a sample. I want to calculate the pairwise distance between those samples according to the formula `d = 1-1/(2p)sum(a/c+b/d)` where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` can treated as as the row vector of length `10000` according to some definition and `p=10000`. `c` and `d` are probabilities such that `c+d=1`.

An example of how to find the values of `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`: suppose we want to find `d` between sample `i` and b`j`, then I look at row `i` and `j`.

If `k`th entry of row `i` and `j` has value `2` and `2`, then `a=2,b=0,c=1,d=0` (I guess I will assign `0/0=0` in this case).

If `k`th entry of row `i` and `j` has value `2` and `1` or vice versa, then `a=1,b=0,c=3/4,d=1/4`.

The similar assignment will give to the case for `2,0`(`a=0,b=0,c=1/2,d=1/2`),`1,1`(`a=1,b=1,c=1/2,d=1/2`),`1,0`(`a=0,b=1,c=1/4,d=3/4`),`0,0`(`a=0,b=2,c=0,d=1`).

The matlab code I have so far is using `for` loops for `i` and `j`, then find the cases above by using `find`, then create two arrays for `a/c` and `b/d`. This is extremely slow, is there a way that I can improve the efficiency?

Edit: the distance `d` is the formula given in [this paper](http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0029901&representation=PDF) on page 13.

Comment: [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) or [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)? Also, showing your code might be more helpful. Or better, [a minimal, complete, tested and readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, because the question's really about how to _optimise_ the distance function, rather than how to _apply_ it.

Comment: @Notlikethat: I think you may be right. I've edited the title to try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided those coefficients are fixed, then I *think* I've successfully vectorised the distance function. Figuring out the formulae was fun. I flipped things around a bit to minimise division, and since I wasn't aware of `pdist` until @horchler's comment, you get it wrapped in loops with the constants factored out:

```
% m is the data
[n p] = size(m, 1);
distance = zeros(n);
for ii=1:n
    for jj=ii+1:n
        a = min(m(ii,:), m(jj,:));
        b = 2 - max(m(ii,:), m(jj,:));
        c = 4 ./ (m(ii,:) + m(jj,:));
        c(c == Inf) = 0;
        d = 1 - c;

        distance(ii,jj) = sum(a.*c + b.*d);
        % distance(jj,ii) = distance(ii,jj); % optional for the full matrix
    end
end
distance = 1 - (1 / (2 * p)) * distance;
```